# How Can I replace this type "int" by"String" in c programming?

Tags: c

I'm using dev c++ . This is silly program which ask the correct key to show a text. This program working perfectly with type "int" (just numbers):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>

    main()
    {
        int key;

        printf("This program show a mensage if you get the correct key \n");
        printf("Write the key:\n");
        scanf("%i",&key);
            if(key==1234)
            {
                printf("Welcome to stackoverflow \n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("You keep going slept \n");
            }
            getch();    
         return 0;

    }
```

But How can I replace for strings for example: sesame, house and so on.

I've tried by matrix:

```
char key[];
```

However i get Error.

Sincerily
NIN.

***Update:***

I could get a new program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

main()
{
    char key[7]; /*replace int for char*/

    printf("This program show a mensage if you get the correct key \n");
    printf("Write the key:\n");
    scanf("%c",&key);
        if(key=="sesame") /*numbers for string*/
        {
            printf("Welcome to stackoverflow \n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("You keep going slept \n");
        }
        getch();    
     return 0;

}
```

However even though I fix the correct key ("sesame") I just get "You keep going slept"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1:

```
scanf("%c",&key);
```

is not right. It will read just one character. You need to use

```
scanf("%6s", key);
```

Problem 2:

```
    if(key=="sesame")
```

is not the proper way to compare two strings. It will compare two pointers and will evaluate to false. You need to use:

```
    if( strcmp(key, "sesame") == 0 )
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot compare value of strings using == operator

```
      if(key=="sesame") // This compares pointers
```

You need

```
      if(strcmp(key,"sesame") == 0)
```

See: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm

Also

```
  scanf("%c",&key);
```

will not work. %c gets only 1 character.
You need %s for string.

```
int ret =  scanf("%6s", key); // or scanf("%6s", &key[0]); 
if (ret < 0)
     {
     // The function returns the number of input items successfully matched and assigned,
     // which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.
     // The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the 
     // first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. EOF is also returned 
     // if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set indicate the error.
     // see: http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf
     }
```

Note that you need just `key` or `&key[0]` as a pointer to the `key` buffer.

Comment: Perhaps checking the return value of `scanf` would be wise along with using `scanf("'%6s", ....` to ensure no buffer overruns

Comment: @EdHeal I agree! Protecting the buffer from overrun is important! I have improved the code.

Comment: Your comment (`if successfull ....`) is incorrect - see [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

Comment: @EdHeal I based my comment on this link:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/?kw=scanf has more description

Comment: That is incorrect. See the manual page or try it yourself. PS: Scanf does not write - it reads

Comment: @EdHeal  OK! I understand. It reads from input. I was interpreting statement "characters written" as characters written to the buffer. I am improving the answer according to your suggestion.

Comment: It is not the total number of characters. Please re-read the manual page

Comment: @EdHeal Thank you for your comment! I have quoted the information from the [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) link to improve the answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *a = "sesame";

    printf("this program show a message if you get the correct key \n");

    printf("write the correct key:\n");

    //  scanf("%c",&key);

    if(a == "sesame")
    {   
        printf("welcome to stack overflow \n"); 
    }
    else
    {
        printf("you keep going to sleep \n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```